# Why doesn't `std::lock` lock mutexes using a global ordering?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

`std::lock` and `std::scoped_lock` can be used to lock a series of mutexes while avoiding a deadlock. Apparently, they use some algorithm composed of `lock`s, `try_lock`s and `unlocks` to achieve this.

As it should be simpler, couldn't `std::lock` and `std::scoped_lock` lock the mutexes using some kind of global ordering (such as their address taken with `&`), as a deadlock does not occur when mutexes are always locked in the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can deadlock with other algorithms. Suppose one lock protects a collection of objects and another lock protects an individual object in that collection. Code that doesn't call `std::lock` will lock the collection first, then find the object, and then want to acquire the lock that protects that particular object.

If your algorithm was used, then what happens if code in the object uses `std::lock` to acquire both locks and your algorithm says to acquire the lock that protects the object before the lock that protects the collection? It would deadlock.

Comment: You can't possibly lock a collection and its element in one call, as you need to reach into a locked collection first to get to the element. Need a more realistic example.

Comment: @rustyx The example is that you already have the element. For example, you may be removing the element from the collection. That's not unrealistic at all. Consider: 1) You lock the collection. 2) You lock the element. 3) You unlock the collection. 4) You decide to remove the element from the collection. 5) You lock the collection to do so, already holding the lock on the element.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm works for any lockable object—some of those might be wrappers for other locks (like `std::unique_lock`), so checking addresses would be insufficient.  Nothing stops the library from recognizing that all types involved are “primitive” locks from the standard library and applying your suggestion.